# How to install Northwind Database on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sql, mssql

I have installed MSSQL server , i tried creating tables and inserting , it worked well but i want to install Northwind Database , so i am asking if i can install it on ubuntu.

Comment: What did not work? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/master/sample/northwind_ddl.sql    has plain text commands so I would expect you to just execute them?

Comment: and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/master/sample/northwind_data.sql has the data

Comment: Are you sure that this for MS SQL server..? as it caused syntax errors while executing the second file , and i don't see in the beginning of the commands any creation of database should i create database first then i type "**use database name** " then execute these commands ......

Comment: You always create the database yourself. "are you sure that this for MS SQL server..?" those scripts are the commands you issue from the windows software to set this up so yet. They look good to me ;)

Comment: I have searched about this , and the problem is that copying from web pages may have unprintable characters that causes syntax error , so i am asking you if you have an idea about removing these unprintable characters .